# CentOS 7 SSH login with Keys Authentication

Tags: linux

Is there any possibility to create one master account (for one master laptop for example), from which I can log in to all accounts available on the server ?

My server has Keys Authentication enabled and PasswordAuthentication disabled.

Now, after reboot I can login to server from my (master laptop) as root, but I can not login as a regular user, I get „access denied".

Comment: I think more information is needed to be able to know what is the exact issue.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/108215/215599

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will first need to log in as the master or root account, and then `sudo su otheruser` in order to log in as that user. There is no way to log in as any user without first going through a privleged user's account.

An additional caveat is that the user you are trying to log in as needs to have a shell of `/bin/bash` or similar valid shell in `/etc/passwd`. If the user has a shell like `/bin/fase` or `/bin/nologin` you will be unable to change to this user's account (but neither will anyone else for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

edit your /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/all_users_authorized_keys
```

Put your pubkey in that file, and restart the sshd.

See:
https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/openssh

The default behavior (which we are all probably familiar with) is

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```